What is this notion of differentiability?
The standard definition for the derivative of a function $f: R^n \to R^m$ at a point $x_0$ is the unique linear map, $f'(x_0): R^n \to R^m$, such that
$$ \lim_{x \to x_o}\frac{\|f(x) - f(x_0) - f'(x_0)(x - x_0)\|}{\|x - x_0\|} = 0$$
On the other hand, the brain-dead generalization of the single-variable definition might be something like this:
$$f'_{stupid}(x_0) =  \lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{\|x - x_0\|}$$
which seems to say something like "no matter what direction I take to approach $x_0$, the "$m$-d slope'' of $f$ is the same and is equal to $f'_{stupid}(x_0$)." Or, on other words, that all directional derivatives are equal to $f'_{stupid}(x_0)$.
Can anyone shed some light on any relations between the two?

It is worth noting that the first definition actually bakes in the concept of a "direction" being applied. Your second definition almost surely doesnt exist unless the function has 0 slope, because any slanted surface will have a different value of the derivative depending on the direction you approach from (notably the denominator is always positive, unlike the "h" we see in the usual derivative).

Yeah I’m pretty sure it only exists for constant functions and is equal to zero haha

I would think $f(x) = 1 + \lVert x \rVert$ has $f'{stupid}(0) = 1$, though of course 0 would then be the only point where $f'{stupid}(x)$ exists.

It might be worth noting that in your brain-dead-definition for $m=1$, if you replace the lim with a limsup, you more or less get what is called a "local slope" (up to a few technicalities). In $R^n$ this is of course less useful, but the point is that the definition still works in metric spaces, as a replacement of $|\nabla f|$.

One relation between these two definitions is that if the first definition holds then the limit in the braid-dead definition does not even exist (outside of a very exceptional case).
The thing to keep in mind is that in order for a multidimensional limit $\lim_{x \to x_0}$ to exist, the value of the limit must be the same no matter how $x$ approaches $x_0$. This even holds in the 1-dimensional case of course: we require the left and right limits to be equal, in order for the limit to exist.
So, let's suppose that the first (correct) definition holds, and consider the linear transformation $f'(x_0) : R^n \to R^m$. Suppose that $f'(x_0)$ is not the zero transformation, in other words there exists a unit vector $u \in R^n$ such that the image vector $w = f'(x_0)(u)$ is not the zero vector. Then the limit that defines $f'_{stupid}(x_0)$ does not exist. To prove this, first let $x$ approach $x_0$ along the ray $x_0 + t u$ for $t > 0$ you get a certain nonzero value which is
$$\lim_{t \to 0^+} \frac{f(x_0+tu) - f(x_0)}{\| t u \|}  = f'(x_0)(u) = w
$$
whereas if you let $x$ approach $x_0$ along the ray $x_0 + t \vec u$ for $t < 0$ then you get the opposite value
$$\lim_{t \to 0^-} \frac{f(x_0+tu) - f(x_0)}{\| t u \|} = f'(x_0)(-u) = -w
$$
The exceptional case is that $f'(x_0)$ is the zero transformation, in which case all directional deriatives are zero, the limit in the brain dead definition exists, and its value is zero.
